# msAccess add data to multiple rows where there is a match

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, insert-into

I have a large list of values to add to a new column on a ms Access database (unfortunately the data is stored on SharePoint lists).

The database holds customer ID's and I need to add data to a new column where data will be specific to each customer ID.

My spread sheet of data to add is for example:

```
Cust ID | DataToAdd
  1     |   Car
  2     |   Boat
  3     |   Bike
  4     |   Plane
```

My table is set up similar to:

```
Cust ID | Location | DataToAdd
  1     |  Europe  |
  2     |  Asia    |
  3     |  Africa  |
  4     |  US      |
```

I know how to insert the values individually (but the data is thousands of records long) using:

```
Insert Into [MyTable] (DataToAdd) Values (Car)
where [Cust ID] = 1
```

Is there a way to do this on bulk to add all of the DataToAdd column to the table where the CustID's are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Create a staging table with your new data.

```
[stagingTable]
Cust ID | DataToAdd
  1     |   Car
  2     |   Boat
  3     |   Bike
  4     |   Plane
```

and Update your destination table

```
UPDATE [MyTable]
INNER JOIN [stagingTable] ON [MyTable].[Cust ID] = [stagingTable].[Cust ID]
SET [MyTable].[DataToAdd] = [stagingTable].[DataToAdd]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A staging table is definitely a good idea.  You can also use `switch`:

update t
    set datatoadd = switch(customerid = 1, 'car',
                           customerid = 2, 'boat',
                           customerid = 3, 'bike',
                           customerid = 4, 'plane',
                           1=1, datatoadd
                          );
```

You can construct each of the conditions using a formula in the spreadsheet.  That can make generating such a query pretty easy.